# De un document como podria filtrar los resultados de un query por el valor mas frecuente en mongoDB?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

**Quisiera que de este objeto**

```
db.restaurants.insertMany( [
   {tag: "comida", opcion:"papas"},
   { tag: "comida", opcion:"pastel"},
   { tag: "bebida", opcion:"agua"},
   { tag: "bebida", opcion:"soda"},
   { tag: "bebida", opcion:"limonada"},
   { tag: "dulce", opcion:"chocolate"}
] );
```

**Me regrese algo como esto**

```
[
{tag:"comida", opcion: {papas,pastel,}},
{tag:"bebida", opcion: {agua,soda,limonada}},
{tag:"dulce", opcion: {chocolate,}},
]
```

Hasta el momento solo he logrado contar cuantos de cada tag diferente hay usando el siguiente codigo

```
Posts.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$tags" },  { $sortByCount: "$tags" }
  ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La salida que esperas (la que muestras en tu pregunta) no sería una salida válida, ya que esto:

```js
{tag:"comida", opcion: {papas,pastel,}},
```

no es un objeto válido en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). Supongo que la salida esperada es:

```js
{tag:"comida", opcion: ["papas", "pastel"]},
```

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea agrupar datos de una colección en MongoDB de acuerdo a un campo específico. Lo que tienes actualmente no sería una agregación que produzca algún resultado de provecho (si tomamos en cuenta que el campo `tags` no está definido en la colección `restaurants`, tal como lo muestra tu código, donde se define el campo `tag`, en singular).

Luego, más adelante se ve que usas un proceso de agregación sobre un modelo de datos llamado `Posts`, por lo cual asumiré que tu modelo de datos `Posts` apunta a la colección `restaurants` que mencionas al principio de tu pregunta.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Suponiendo que la colección es la que muestras en la primera parte de tu pregunta, lo que buscas hacer es una agrupación ([`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group)) sobre el campo `tag`. Por ejemplo:

```js
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$tag",
    "opcion": {
      $push: "$opcion"
    }
  }
}
```

En la etapa `$group` anterior se están agrupando todos los documentos por valor del campo `tag` (es decir, en el campo `_id` estoy usando el valor de `tag` como clave única) y los elementos del campo `opcion` los estoy incorporando a una lista (`Array`) llamada `opcion`, usando el operador de agregación [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

Esto me devuelve documentos de la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  _id: "comida",
  opcion: [
    "papas",
    "pastel"
  ]
}
```

Luego podemos usar una etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) para cambiar el nombre del campo `_id` por `tag`, de esa forma el resultado es el esperado:

```js
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,        // <- indico que no devuelva el campo _id
    opcion: 1,     // <- indico que sí devuelva el campo opcion
    tag: "$_id"    // <- indico que el campo tag tome el valor de _id
  }
}
```

De esta forma, la salida sería la siguiente:

```js
{
  opciones: [
    "papas",
    "pastel"
  ],
  tag: "comida"
}
```

(Recordemos que los campos se ordenan por defecto de acuerdo al orden de la etapa anterior).

Puedes ver un ejemplo de lo anterior en el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A2D38gffaZM).